# Is there a masked textbox for Kendo-UI

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-maskedtextbox

I have not found any kind of masked input support for KendoUI is there anything planned for a future release? Can I have access to a preview version?

Comment: You should be able to achieve masked input with a jquery plug-in (for example http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[No, it does not exist yet](http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/127393-telerik-kendo-ui-feedback/suggestions/2404523-just-a-mask-edit)

```
UNDER REVIEW  ·   Kenshin, Kendo UI Team
ADMIN
Kenshin, Kendo UI Team (Admin, Kendo UI) responded  ·  Nov 22, 2011
Masked input widget will be contemplated for the future versions of Kendo UI.
```

Please everyone add your votes!!!

**Update:**

> ADMIN Kenshin, Kendo UI Team (Admin, Telerik Kendo UI) responded  · 
>   March 20, 2014 Masked textbox widget is included in Q1 2014.

**Update 2:** [Documentation Link!](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/maskedtextbox)

Answer (score 5):

From release 2014.1.321 there are masked input. The name of the widget is `kendoMaskedTextBox` and the documentation can be found [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/maskedtextbox).

Some examples on how to use can be found on their [demo page](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/maskedtextbox/index.html) and is as simple as:

Phone number:

```
<input id="phone_number" value="555 123 4567"/>

$("#phone_number").kendoMaskedTextBox({
    mask: "(999) 000-0000"
});
```

Credit card:

```
<input id="credit_card" value="1234 1234 1234 1234"/>

$("#credit_card").kendoMaskedTextBox({
    mask: "0000 0000 0000 0000"
});
```

The mask definition syntax is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply. But maskedtextbox loses its value after post the view to the controller. How to fix it?